# Loading spinner in DurandalJS always work

Tags: durandal

I'm try to add loading spinner animation for my DurandalJS project. I add the spinet like this:

```
<li class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { active: router.isNavigating }">
 <img src="~/Content/images/menuContent/load.png" style="width: 50px; height:50px;"/>
</li>
```

But my animation always work. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use another css class that make the **li** **display** *to* **none**, maybe you have a css rule that override the **display** of the li, see the example:

```
.example-visible{
    display:none !important;
}
<li class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { example-visible: router.isNavigating }">
<img src="~/Content/images/menuContent/load.png" style="width: 50px;  height:50px;"/>
</li>
```